# Python code not writing output in excel sheet but is able to take input from another sheet in same workbook

Tags: python, excel, excel-2016, xlwings

Background:
I am fetching Option chain for a symbol from web and then writing it to an excel sheet. I also have another excel sheet in the same workbook from which I take inputs for the program to run. All of this I am doing with excel 2016.

Sample of the code from program as the whole program is pretty long:

```
import xlwings as xw
excel_file = 'test.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(excel_file)
wb.save()
# Fetching User input for Script/Ticker else it will be set to NIFTY as default
try:
    Script_Input = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = 'Input_Options', usecols = 'C')
    script = Script_Input.iloc[0,0]
except:
    script = 'NIFTY'
# Writing data in the sheet
sht_name = script + '_OC'
    try:
        wb.sheets.add(sht_name)
        print('new sheet added')
        wb.save()
    except:
        pass
        # print('sheet already present')
    # directing pointer towards current sheet to be written
    sheet = wb.sheets(sht_name)
    sheet.range('A4').options(index = False, header = False).value = df
    sheet.range('B1').value = underlying
    sheet.range('C1').value = underlying_Value
    # sheet.range('A3').options(index = False, header = False).value = ce_data_final
    # sheet.range('J3').options(index = False, header = False).value = pe_data_final
    wb.save()
```

Problem: Since yesterday, I am able to open my excel workbook with excel 2016 and change inputs for my program but, I do not get any data written in the sheet that takes output from the program. The program runs perfectly as I can test the output on terminal. Also, once I delete the sheet no new sheet is being created as it should.
What I tried: I have uninstalled every other version of excel I had, so now only excel 2016 is present.
I have made sure that all the respective file formats use excel 2016 as the default app.

Also note that, 2 days ago I was able to write data perfectly in the respective sheet but now I am not able to do so.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: did you make recent changes in the script?  note that indentation in your snippet is off at the moment and will cause IndentationError, unless it's a problem with formatting of your post here on the site. Also we don't know what df is (possible problems there?).

Comment: @buran please ignore the indentation in post. The input and out parts are written in different places in the code. The code shows no error and runs as intended except for the fact that I do not see any output written in the sheet.
There is one more thing I have no idea how to clarify.
I had office desktop apps installed on PC, which I never use. I used excel 2016 and is default app for all excel activities on my PC.Today, when I ran the program in morning I saw output on Microsoft desktop app excel rather than 2016 excel. So, I uninstalled Microsoft Desktop app. And now I face this problem.

Comment: if we ignore the indentation, there is little we can help. More over - if this is not the actual code, but short version of it - make sure it is runnable and reproduce the error/problem. I am not sure I understand your concern with excel apps and what distinction you make between excel 2016 and desktop excel app. Not that I think it matters unless you run python code from within excel.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to everyone who tried to solve this question.
after @buran asked about 'df' I looked into my code and found that I had a  `return` statement before writing 'df' into sheet (I have created a separate function to write data in excel). Now that I have moved that statement to its proper place the code is working fine. I am extremely sorry as I did not realise what the problem was in the 1st place and assumed it had to do with excel and python. Now the program runs perfectly and I am getting the output I want.